# ViewPager with header view should scroll to correct position?

Tags: android, listview, header, viewpage

I want to make an effect like twitter profile.

I use a ViewPager, and each Fragment has a ListView.
Each ListView has a header as a placeholder view.
I have a register callback method, so when the ListView Scrolls, in the main Activity header.setTranslationY will be invoked.
In onPageSelected, the adjustScroll method will be called to make the ListView scroll to the correct position, but I cannot get the right position

How to make [this](http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/5f5f92d8gw1eqlm0wgttlj20u01hc12k.jpg)?

Comment: http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/5f5f92d8gw1eqlm0s3iezj20u01hcqhh.jpg

Comment: http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/5f5f92d8gw1eqlm0kl6w2j20u01hcn6w.jpg